# What does "and the like" mean?

Tags: word-usage

What does `and the like` actually mean and how do I use that in a sentence properly?

Comment: Did you try looking it up? What is confusing you about it?  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/and+the+like

Comment: @nxx `John just loves hot dogs, hamburgers, french fries, and the like`. For someone who doesn't understand `and the like`, that example doesn't help much I think.

Comment: @ thefourtheye It was the definition I was pointing you to: "and more of the same". Other dictionaries might put it in slightly different ways and give different usage examples. It is a good idea to have a look through a few of them.

Comment: @nxx Anyway Thanks :) Josh's answer helps me understand it better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

And the Like:

And similar things; et cetera.

EXAMPLES:

I owe some of my initial successes to old friends at Oxford who put me in touch with publishers and the like.

I've spent the entire day sorting and washing baby clothes and the like.

The boot includes hooks for shopping bags and the like and the exterior is enhanced by alloy wheels.

Source: Oxfordonline Dic.

Comment: can it be used as " something like that"?

Comment: @アレックス - I'd say so, what sentence do you have in mind?

Comment: any. for example, "you can go there, relax, play and the like" and the like.

Answer (score 1):

It means "and similar" or according to [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/and+the+like) "and more of the same".

> Idioms & Phrases
>
> and the like
>
> And more of the same, as in John just loves hot dogs, hamburgers,
>   french fries, and the like . [c. 1600]